How is an R01 grant typically split?
Let's say an NIH R01 grant pays $500,000 per year in total cost. And the PI does not have any other grants.
How does this get split, typically? $200,000 to the institution, $150,000 to the PI and the rest to students and postdocs?
Or does the institution typically cover half of the PI's compensation, unless he has multiple grants?

I don't think "typical" is very useful; you have to write a budget that accounts for the money needed for the proposed project. Your institution should have grants staff specifically to help you with this sort of thing.

I'd say more that NIH pays the institution $500k for the benefit of the grant proposal. Talk to the experts at your institution.

While this question is predicated on a misunderstanding, it's surely one shared by people at the foot of the ivory tower. I think it should remain open, especially with the excellent answer that's been given.

The question is based on the misunderstanding that the receiving institution or PI gets to choose how to spend the money. But that's wrong. The decision has already been made at the time of submitting the proposal, where you need to provide a budget that in some detail says how the money will be spent. You're largely tied to those choices when you actually receive the grant.

Research administrator here; I have made hundreds of budgets for faculty in the sciences.  There is no such thing as "typical" that will be specific enough to give the "right" answer.  There are guiding principles though.  Here is the general approach.
First you need to look at your solicitation and see if there are any restrictions to the budget.  R01s that are under the parent solicitation do not have a ceiling, but that doesn't mean most people propose $20M projects.  If your direct costs exceed a certain amount in any year, you need to file additional paperwork for approval.  This detail is in the solicitation or R&R guide.  This necessarily keeps the amounts lower.
With NIH, you budget direct costs and then indirect costs (IDC)/facilities and administration (F&A) costs are added on top.  This is different from other sponsors.  So if your institution has an IDC/F&A rate of 50%, you budget $100,000 direct costs, and all those costs are subject to IDC/F&A, then your total budget request is $150k.
So at this point the budget is yours to make.  What do you need?  Do you have collaborators?  At this point, single-PI R01s are the rare exception.  You need to work with your local research administrator to figure out what you can afford.  For junior PIs, I recommend 1 month of effort unless it looks like they are getting overcommitted.  For senior PIs, usually 0.25 unless this project matters more to their work, and then I ask them to peg the amount.  Some of them actually want it lowered down to 0.10 because of effort commitments.  Unlike other agencies, NIH requires paid effort on the grant for all PIs and Co-Is.
In terms of dividing up the direct costs, I have found PIs have two types of fairness:

Divide the dollars equally; thus if direct costs are $500k/year for a proposal with two PIs, then each gets $250k/year.
Predominately fund the junior PI first (e.g., give them effort and a student) and then divide the remainder equally with senior PIs.

It's also possible to scope out specific aspects of a project first, e.g., if you want to fund a workshop or travel is taken out of the total pool as a "reserve", and the rest of the funding is divided equally, with travel added back in to ensure that a certain amount of travel is budgeted (this is more common in CS, where travel to conferences is like publication funding and with sponsors where IDC counts against the total budget, like NSF or DOD).
It is really up to the PIs.  Whether or not you are junior or senior, I would recommend finding a more senior person to talk to.  I can give you all this guidance, but in the end, you also need to think about your local culture, policies, and procedures.  If you work at a hospital, these rules are probably about 70% accurate.  If you work with hospitals, you have to understand there is a culture gap.  They are funding researchers on 12-month, soft-money appointments.  Academia budgets likely have tuition costs that don't take IDC/F&A.  Many budgets that mix academia and hospitals are confused about these types of culture gaps.
Talk to your assigned research administrator, and they should be able to guide you appropriately, but in general, you have to make the decisions within the rules your research admin gives you.

What is "R&R" and "IDC/F&A"?

@AzorAhai-him-, as noted prior, IDC is indirect costs and F&A are Facilities and Administration.  The forms usually have the abbreviations listed, not the full words.  R&R is the name of the application guide for NIH (no one says "research & related*).  https://grants.nih.gov/grants/how-to-apply-application-guide.html  See also: https://grants.nih.gov/grants/how-to-apply-application-guide/format-and-write/develop-your-budget.htm

Oh, I see it now. I'm used to acronym definitions appearing after they're introduced. Thank you for clarifying.

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin as always, your answers are insightful and well thought-out. I apricate your perspective from the admin side of academia!

@RichardErickson, thank you!  I should say, I have myself been educated by many PIs over the years, which is why I am more understanding about motivations and what works.  I've worked with over a hundred PIs making their budgets, so it helps to see that there are different approaches; some common, some not so much (although they can be the most interesting).  Some PIs talk out their approach with me, which makes me better at my job, and I pay it forward by giving that advice to junior PIs as they come along.  What really helps me is when PIs tell me how the reviews went; wish more did that.

If a PI has only one r01, who's paying his salary, typically? -- this is what was trying to ask.

@MWB, this depends on your university policies.  Some PIs are on 9-month salaries paid by their institution, others have 10-months, etc.  If you are on a 9-month salary, then you are not guaranteed a 12-month salary.  You fundraise the remaining 3 months.  Many PIs do not get 12-month salaries because of this.  So if you are on a 9-month salary and get this R01 with 1 month salary, you could be paid up to 10 months.  Soft-money PIs start at 0 months and have to fundraise all 12 months.  You need to check your local policies as to what model your institution uses.
